# Variable External Links based on `sphinx-build` destination (eg: html vs pdf)

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

How can I have sphinx add a link that varies based on the build destination, such as html or pdf?

I'd like to add an external link to my reStructuredText file such that it points to:

1. `example.com/a` when sphinx is building an html file and
2. `example.com/b` when sphinx is building a pdf file

How can I update my source `.rst` files with variable external links with a conditional based on the build destination format?

Comment: Have a look at [`ifconfig`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/ifconfig.html). Although this does not tie directly to `make pdf/html`, you could include a configuration argument to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like sphinx has some limitations on declaring targets conditionally using `ifconfig` per https://stackoverflow.com/q/63129590/1174102 A simple extension might be more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

I was successfully able to generate targets conditionally based on the `buildername` by using a simple python sphinx extension.

## Preface

First, it's worth noting that the `buildername` (`html` for html or `rinoh` for pdf) is not made available to `conf.py` or extensions as [the builder is setup *after* the extensions when the Sphinx class is initialized](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/b37675607bebae26793bde730c51d582f7de7a30/sphinx/application.py#L242-L247).

To overcome this, I choose to [parse `sys.argv`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3740#issuecomment-385503305), but this might not work if you build sphinx from python rather than calling `sphinx-build` from bash [as I do](https://github.com/maltfield/rtd-github-pages/blob/871561a237c1cd5311217b5c0e487f9639bd562b/docs/buildDocs.sh#L66-L82).

A more robust solution might be to [use a tag](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/7847#issuecomment-647110210).

## conf.py

First, add the following block somewhere the sphinx `conf.py` file, which will make an environment variable named 'buildername' available from extensions:

```
def setup(app):

   argv = ' '.join(sys.argv)
   if '-b html' in argv:
      app.add_config_value('buildername', 'html', 'env')
   else:
      app.add_config_value('buildername', 'not-html', 'env')
```

Then update your `extensions` list to include `conditionaltarget`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('_extensions'))
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'conditionaltarget',
]
```

## _extensions/conditionaltarget.py

Create the example "Conditional Target" extension at `docs/_extensions/conditionaltarget.py` with the following contents:

```
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import Directive

from sphinx.locale import _
from sphinx.util.docutils import SphinxDirective

class ConditionalTarget(SphinxDirective):

    def run(self):
        target_node = nodes.target( '', '' )
        target_node['names'] = ['targetname1']

      if self.env.config.buildername == 'html':
            target_node['refuri'] = 'https://example.com/a'
        else:
            target_node['refuri'] = 'https://example.com/b'

        return [target_node]

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive("conditionaltarget", ConditionalTarget)

    return {
        'version': '0.1',
        'parallel_read_safe': True,
        'parallel_write_safe': True,
    }
```

## index.rst

Finally, adding the following to the source `.rst` file:

```
test link to targetname1_

.. conditionaltarget::
```

Now the link should point to `example.com/a` when built using `sphinx-build -b html . _build/html/` and `example.com/b` when built using with any other command that doesn't include `-b html` (eg `sphinx-build -b rinoh . _build/html/`)

Of course, this is just a very crude proof-of-concept, and a better extension would take inputs from its directive by parsing the newline-delimited `self.content` list for target names and URIs.