# Possible to define a target conditonally using `ifconfig` block (reStructuredText)

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is it possible to condtionally define a [target](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-targets) in a reStructuredText file using [ifconfig](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/ifconfig.html)?

I've set a variable in my sphinx `conf.py` file that I want to use to conditionally determine the URI of a target in my documentation:

```
def setup(app):

    argv = ' '.join(sys.argv)
    if '-b html' in argv:
        app.add_config_value('buildername', 'html', 'env')
    else:
        app.add_config_value('buildername', 'not-html', 'env')
```

And my `index.rst` file has the following content:

```
test link to target1_

.. ifconfig:: buildername == 'html'

  .. _target1: https://example.com/a
```

The above works as expected, and "target1" becomes a hyperlink to `example.com/a`

But if I want to actually define `target1` to be conditionally set to one of two options based on the value of the `buildername` config var, then I have

```
test link to target1_

.. ifconfig:: buildername == 'html'

  .. _target1: https://example.com/a

.. ifconfig:: buildername != 'html'

  .. _target1: https://example.com/b
```

Not only does the above output not work for `example.com/b`, but it breaks the first link and `target1` now points to nothing (actually `#id3`).

Moreover, I get the following warnings in my `sphinx-build` output

```
user@host:~$ make clean && sphinx-build -b html . _build/html/
...
reading sources... [100%] support                                               
.../index.rst:16: WARNING: Duplicate explicit target name: "target1".
.../index.rst:8: WARNING: Duplicate target name, cannot be used as a unique reference: "target1".
...
```

Is it possible to define the same target twice within a `.rst` file, such that each definition is wrapped in an `ifconfig` directive?

Comment: I think this is related to similar issues with the `only` directive. See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2150

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not think what you want is possible.  You could suppress warnings (which is probably not a good idea), or you could add more markup to avoid them through a one-to-one relationship between target and link.

```
.. ifconfig:: buildername == 'html'

    test link to target1_

.. ifconfig:: buildername == 'html'

    .. _target1: https://example.com/a

.. ifconfig:: buildername != 'html'

    test link to target2_

.. ifconfig:: buildername != 'html'

    .. _target2: https://example.com/b
```

Comment: is it possible to suppress a specific subset of warnings?

Comment: Yes: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-suppress_warnings. However it looks like this type of warning cannot be suppressed. Try out all the options and see if you still get this warning type. If it cannot be suppressed, you could ignore the warnings.

Comment: Is it really necessary to  have four `ifconfig` directives?

Comment: Yes, assuming that each `ifconfig` is located in discontiguous places across the documentation.